# making a TreeGraph VertexLabel that contains a text label and also a Tooltip?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to make a [TreeGraph[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TreeGraph.html) that has as labels for vertices both text and Tooltip. The text displays all the time, when the `TreeGraph` is plotted, and in addition, when the mouse moves over the vertex, another text shows up using `Tooltip` (may be below the static text, but I'll worry about this later). This Tooltip text will contain more information about the node.

Right now, I can do each one of the above separately but can't figure how to combine them.

I'll show my attempts below. This is all using V9

#### Tooltip shows up when mouse on vertex

```
TreeGraph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3},
 VertexLabels -> {"Name", 3 -> Placed["equation 1", Tooltip]}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

#### standard vertex label

```
TreeGraph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3},
 VertexLabels -> {"Name"}, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Attempts to combine them

I noticed that it says in the help that any expression can be used as label:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### attempt 1

Since any expression can be used as label, then I tried `Column`

```
TreeGraph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3},
 VertexLabels -> {"Name", 
   3 -> Column[{"3", Placed["equation 1", Tooltip]}]}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

Which does not work.
[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### attempt 2

```
TreeGraph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3},
 VertexLabels -> {"Name", 
   3 -> Labeled[Placed["equation 1", Tooltip], "3"]}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### attempt3

The strange thing is that one can add a button that changes the color of the node and speaks when clicked and also add a Tooltip at the same time, but so hard to add a text in addition to Tooltip

```
TreeGraph[{1, 2, Button[Style[3, Red], Speak["Vertex 3"]]}, {1 -> 2, 
  1 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> {"Name", 
   3 -> Placed["equation 1", Tooltip]}, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
Tried maybe another 10 different ways, too boring to show. So I gave up. I am a newbie in using Graphs in Mathematica, only today I started looking at them.

**Question** How make a label for Vertex and also show Toolip when mouse is on Vertex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tooltip` appears to achieve what you are looking for.

```
TreeGraph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, 
VertexLabels -> {"Name", 3 -> Tooltip["3", "Equation 1"]}, ImagePadding -> 20]
```