# How to place all graph's vertexes names in Tooltip?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, output-formatting, tooltip

I want to render a graph displaying nodes labels only inside Tooltip, not rendered on the graph.

How can I map Tooltip to all vertexes in `VertexLabels -> "Name"` ?

I saw:
[Graph, ToolTip, and Labeled: How to make a swanky graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125412/44334)
and
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17126/44334

I see a syntax like:

```
TreeGraph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, 
VertexLabels -> {"Name", 3 -> Tooltip["3", "Equation 1"]}, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

where Tooltip is applied to a *specific node*, instead I want only a Tooltip for all nodes.

In my example vertex labels would be "1", "2" and "3".

I tried with:

```
VertexLabels -> Tooltip["Name"]

Tooltip /@ VertexLabels -> "Name"

VertexLabels -> {Tooltip["Name"]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost got it :-)  It's

```
VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Tooltip]
```

This usage is shown in [`VertexLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexLabels.html) -> Scope -> Label Specification.

Comment: Doh! Thank you @Szabolcs